# Pass jsp array variable to external javascript

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, jsp

In my jsp file I have a simple array i get with js trimpath:
JSP code :

```
        <c:forEach items="${requestScope.projectsPermissions}" var="pp">
             <c:out value="${pp.project.name}"/>
        </c:forEach>
```

What I want is to have an array of project names (requestScope.projectsPermissions.project.name) in my external js file. Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this.

Comment: if you give each element a class identifier (e.g. projects) the you can use javascript or jquery to look up these dom elements.

Comment: The thing is that i don`t need these 3 lines in my jsp. This is just to show how i get it in jsp. I only need this arrray in my  js function.

Comment: so make them hidden.

Comment: can you please give me an example how it should look like to be able to get the array value from js

Comment: just search for `array jsp to javascript` - plenty of examples and ways to do

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is to write out HTML, and then retrieve the values via jQuery:

```
<ul id="project-names" style="display:none">
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.projectsPermissions}" var="pp">
        <li data-name="${pp.project.name}"></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

And then with jQuery:

```
var myArray = [];
$('#project-names li').each(function() {
    myArray.push($(this).data('name'));
});
```